# Not Able to Append Pseudo Elements After the Div Properly

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Can you please take a look at this demo ans let me know why I am not able to add the pseudo elements after the div `#map-toc`?

As you can see this is adding the content inside the `#map-toc`

```css
#map-toc {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: width 1.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: width 1.5s ease;
  -o-transition: width 1s ease;
  transition: width 1.5s ease;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 10 !important;
  max-width: 320px;
  background: red;
}

#map-toc::after {
  content: ">>";
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  top: 0px;
  margin-right: -20px;
}
```

```html
  <div id="map-toc"></div>
```

Comment: that's what :after and :before do. They add their content **inside** the element, before and after it's **contents**. It's not like you're adding a sibling to the element, but more of a child. A common misconception, check this video for a better understanding of how the pseudo-elements work https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zGiirUiWslI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to have a pseudo-element appear *next* to the parent as the pseudo-element is a *child* of the parent. As the MDN will tell you,

> Note: The pseudo-elements generated by `::before` and `::after` are **[contained by the element's formatting box](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content)**

In order to achieve what you're looking for, you'd be better off making use of a sibling element, with both elements having **[`position: relative`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)** and [`float: left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float). Note that you'll also need to give your red box a **[`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height)** now.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
#map-toc {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: width 1.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: width 1.5s ease;
  -o-transition: width 1s ease;
  transition: width 1.5s ease;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: red;
}

#map-toc-2 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-toc"></div>
<div id="map-toc-2">&gt;&gt;</div>
```